# How to convert a StackTraceElement[] to a String?

Tags: java, stack-trace

[Thread.getStackTrace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace--) returns `StackTraceElement[]`. How can I convert this to a `String` with the same format as `Exception.printStackTrace()` returns?

To clarify: I don't have an exception, only a thread. I want to display the thread's stack trace using the same format as exception stack traces.

Comment: @Andreas Obviously I did. The format looks nothing like the desired result. Do you want me to mention this explicitly in the question?

Comment: The format of `StackTraceElement.toString()` looks exactly like the each entry of `printStackTrace()`, following the `at`.

Comment: @Andreas You're right. I had missed this. I marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is super easy, you just have to print them, with whatever prefix you want.

To print same as `printStackTrace()`, the prefix would be `"\tat "`.

*Proof*

```
// Show printStackTrace() output
new RuntimeException().printStackTrace(System.out);

// Similar output using getStackTrace()
StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
System.out.println("getStackTrace()");
for (int i = 1; i < stackTrace.length; i++)
    System.out.println("\tat " + stackTrace[i]);
```

*Output*

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at Test.main(Test.java:5)
getStackTrace()
    at Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

Note how `for` loop skipped index 0, since that is the stack frame for `getStackTrace()` itself.

Comment: I wanted to get back a String, not output to stdout, but I get your point. Good catch piggybacking on `StackTraceElement.toString()`. I didn't realize this had the correct format.